# Why does calling Python's 'magic method' not do type conversion like it would for the corresponding operator?

Tags: python, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, magic-methods

When I subtract a float from an integer (e.g. `1-2.0`), Python does implicit type conversion (I think). But when I call what I thought was the same operation using the magic method `__sub__`, it suddenly does not anymore.

What am I missing here? When I overload operators for my own classes, is there a way around this other than explicitly casting input to whatever type I need?

```
a=1
a.__sub__(2.)
# returns NotImplemented
a.__rsub__(2.)
# returns NotImplemented
# yet, of course:
a-2.
# returns -1.0
```

Comment: Reference: [`object.__rsub__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rsub__), [`object.__sub__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__sub__)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`a - b` isn't just `a.__sub__(b)`. It also tries `b.__rsub__(a)` if `a` can't handle the operation, and in the `1 - 2.` case, it's the float's `__rsub__` that handles the operation.

```
>>> (2.).__rsub__(1)
-1.0
```

You ran `a.__rsub__(2.)`, but that's the wrong `__rsub__`. You need the right-side operand's `__rsub__`, not the left-side operand.

---

There is no implicit type conversion built into the subtraction operator. `float.__rsub__` has to handle ints manually. If you want type conversion in your own operator implementations, you'll have to handle that manually too.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `NotImplemented` result that is returned by the calls in the question are the signal to try the reverse method.

Comment: Thanks! I was aware it would try `__rsub__` but didn't know it would reverse the argument order.

Comment: @doppler: It'd be pretty pointless to have the left operand handle both `__sub__` and `__rsub__`. That'd just be two methods with the exact same job, and the right operand would have no opportunity to supply an implementation.

Comment: @user2357112 so `self.__rsub__(other)` really just calls `other.__sub__(self)`, if that makes any sense?

Comment: @doppler: No. `self.__rsub__(other)` is called for `other - self` if `other` can't handle it. Calling `other.__sub__(self)` would be pointless. We already know `other` can't handle it.

Comment: @user2357112 My understanding is that a `TypeError` exception is raised when both `two.__rsub__(one)` and `one.__sub__(two)` return `NotImplemented`.

Answer (score 8):

@user2357112 already said it well but there's nothing like an example.

```
class A:
   def __sub__(self, other):
       print('A.__sub__')
       if not isinstance(other, A):
           return NotImplemented
       return 0

   def __rsub__(self, other):
       print('A.__rsub__')
       if not isinstance(other, A):
           return NotImplemented
       return 0

class B:
   def __sub__(self, other):
       print('B.__sub__')
       if not isinstance(other, B):
           return NotImplemented
       return 0
```

```
a1 = A()
a2 = A()
b = B()

a1 - a2
A.__sub__
# 0
```

Objects `a1` and `a2` are compatible (both type `A`), a valid result is returned.

Next, consider,

```
b - a1
B.__sub__
A.__rsub__
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'B' and 'A'
```

Objects `b` and `a1` are not compatible. First, `b.__sub__` is tried, which returns `NotImplemented`, so `a1.__rsub__` is tried, which also returns `NotImplemented`. So a `TypeError` is raised.

Finally,

```
a1 - b
A.__sub__
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'A' and 'B'
```

This time, `a1.__sub__` is tried first, which returns `NotImplemented`. Now, since `b.__rsub__` is not defined, a `TypeError` is raised.