# Using __add__ on int and str types in Python

Tags: python, addition, built-in

I am trying to understand why the following code provides two different outcomes:

```
int(5).__add__(str(5))
```

Returns

```
NotImplemented
```

Shouldn't it then this return `NotImplemented` as well?

```
a = int(5)
b = str(5)
a+b
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
> While

```
5 + '5'
```

Returns

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

So it knows that the first `5` is an `int` type but can't use it on `5.__add__(5)`

Does `int` class gets initialized differently when I assign an `int` to a variable rather than just using an `int` right away and treats objects differently when used in parentheses?

Comment: Because after `5.` the parser assumes you're writing a floating point number and expects another digit... See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/31037609/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You can follow it with non-digits, though, for example `5.and(4)` happily gets evaluated to `4`.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the first bit, any idea on the second part?

Comment: @superbrain because it's interpreted as `5. and 4`

Comment: What second part? [Edit] your post to ask a single clear question.

Comment: Please ask a new question; the original has already been closed as a separate question, and the edit is a *completely* separate question.

Comment: Are you really asking why `(5).__add__("5")` doesn't do the same as `5 + "5"`? You seem to have several confounding things right now. That would be a duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54775946/3001761.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs, appreciated it.