# Most efficient method to find values in nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have the dict below

```
{
    "1": {
        "rarity": 1
    },
    "2": {
        "rarity": 2
    }
}
```

and I want to find the amount of times `rarity` is 1. Instead of doing

```
count = 0
for x in dict.values():
    if x['rarity'] == 1:
         count += 1
return count
```

Is there a better way to do this? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371856/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-value-in-a-dictionary-in-python) post about using `map`, but I'm not sure how to get it to work with a nested dictionary.

Comment: The way I'd write it is just `sum(1 for v in d.values() if v["rarity"] == 1)`.

Comment: are you interested in knowing the working or just want to use it some where?

Comment: Efficient? In what sense? Also, your code doesn't seem to do what you say it should do.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA with just that small sample set, `count` would be 1.

@MateenUlhaq I guess I'm looking for the "proper" way. I feel like what I have works, but it's not proper because it's iterating each value in a for loop, when I think `map` or `lambda` may work instead. Also `x==4` should be `x['rarity']==1`, my mistake.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq it can be shorter `sum` also counts True values `sum(v["rarity"] == 1 for v in d.values())`

Comment: @rioV8 Nitpick: it's not something special `sum` is doing, that's just how bools work. `0 + True` -> `1`

Comment: more details: `isinstance(True, int)` evaluates to `True`. because `True` is an integer with the value of `1`. it's also its own class `bool`, which is a subclass of `int`.

Comment: len(v for v in d.values() if v["rarity"] == 1)

Comment: @Daniel `len()` doesn't work on iterators.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following helper function with the map.

```
def functionHelper(value):
    if value["rarity"] == 1:
        return 1
    return 0
sum(map(functionHelper, d.values()))
```

or you can use one of these:

```
sum(map((1).__eq__, [v["rarity"] for v in d.values()]))
sum(v["rarity"] == 1 for v in d.values())
```

Comment: I think you accidentally combined the second two options so I edited to fix it.

Comment: The second `map` option has some problems. Use the generator expression instead. 1) Doing a `map` over a list comprehension means that the whole list is created first, *then* mapped. This is pointless and would be inefficient for large `d`. 2) Strongly avoid using dunder methods like `int.__eq__`. For comparison, [`int.__sub__(float)` instead of `int - float` doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54775946/4518341). 3) It's longer and harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it much shorter:

```
count = sum(v["rarity"] == 1 for v in d.values())
```

*<sub>from [rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153547/most-efficient-method-to-find-values-in-nested-dict/65161579#comment115186020_65153547), with inspiration from [Mateen Ulhaq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365102/mateen-ulhaq)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153547/most-efficient-method-to-find-values-in-nested-dict#comment115185966_65153547)</sub>*